# Can't Access Properties From Object Stored In Vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, state

Hey hey I'm a c++ newb here... i would appriciate someone pointing out an apparent misunderstanding i have about pointers and vectors (may be something else). I'm trying to create a switch element that handles several sub states

```
class MotionSwitch: public StateSwitch, public IMotion
{
public:
  MotionSwitch(){ initialize(); };
  ~MotionSwitch(){};

  //Make Motion States
  MotionState restState; //Initialized In _states at 0
  MotionState motionState;//"                     " 1
  MotionState spinState;//"                       " 2

  std::vector<MotionState*>  _states;

};

class MotionState: public State, public IMotion
{
...
String msg = "Hello Is Motion";
...
};
```

The _states vector is initialized like this...

```
void MotionSwitch::initialize()
{
  //Add States In Order Of ENUM (Because It Matters!)
  _states.push_back(&restState);
  _states.push_back(&motionState);
  _states.push_back(&spinState);
}
```

The in following application code only one of the following will print

```
  MotionState *currentState = widget._motionSwitch._states.at(0);
  widget._com.log( "State Message...");
  widget._com.log( currentState -> msg); //Won't Print
  widget._com.log( widget._motionSwitch.restState.msg ); //This WILL Print
```

I would appreciate any help i can get here from you code gods!

Comment: Define "// Won't Print".

Comment: I'm running this code on some embedded hardware... so the serial output won't resolve. If I try to access a method instead of a variable the code will hang forever.

Comment: Do you get an error message with `currentState->msg`?

Comment: Off topic: consider `MotionSwitch():_states{&restState,&motionState,&spinState} {}` instead of the current constructor and init function.

Comment: Most likely because `currentState -> msg` is an invalid pointer/object/whatever undefined behavior. If this object gets copied around, note that copying an object will invalid the pointers in the vector. This is your most likely cause of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Bibi541 sorry no im running on embedded hardware so its not really possible to see a stack trace.. at least that i know of

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik.. do you have any suggestions on where a pointer might become invalidated? from the above code..?

Comment: Build yourself a simulation you can run on an environment you can debug. You'll thank yourself later. It won't pick off the timing and other integration nasties, but you can use the simulation to ensure your logic is sound.

Comment: It would be invalidated anywhere your code moves an instance of the `MotionSwitch` object. This includes explicitly moving it, or passing it by value to a function. Delete the default copy-constructor, and the assignment operator, and let your compiler yell at you everywhere you do that. In fact, given what you're doing with these pointers, and the vector, you should explicitly delete the copy constructor, and the assignment operator, in the `MotionSwitch` class. Making a copy of any instance of the `MotionSwitch` object will invalidate the pointers. As such, this should be prohibited.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik! You were correct :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik... Hey another question.. would you consider initiating this in a different way? Maybe it would be better to dynamically create each substate?

Comment: Another thought: If instead of `vector<MotionState *> _states` you went with `map<ENUM, MotionState *> _states`, the order `MotionState`s are entered into `_states` will not matter. Small performance hit, safety goes way up. `map<ENUM, MotionState> _states` would probably eliminate the need for `restState`, `motionState`, and `spinState`.